# Why is it bad design for a UITableViewCell to send messages to the controller in MVC design?

Tags: model-view-controller, uitableview

I'm wondering what the reasoning is behind apple's decision not to have UITableViewCells know their row and section, even to the point where implementing a custom accessory button is seemingly non trivial and tricky. I thought it was correct to have the controller receive messages from both sides and mediate per se, could anyone explain this? Or is it maybe just a feature they haven't gotten to yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it ties them to the controller.  If the cellViews blindly do what they're told, a wide variety of controllers can re-use them.  If they're sending specific messages to a controller, that cell can only be used by a controller that conforms to that protocol.  It's not the end of the world if a view talks back, but it's just cleaner if the view is out there in la-la land, happy and oblivious.

Comment: That makes sense, it almost seems like making an accessory button call the method from the pre-existing tableViewDelegate protocol would be nicer though, too bad there's no built-in way